# How do the Ruby daemon

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to do the Ruby daemon program. I need to call an action which I defined in the daemon program from my Ruby application. That daemon program may also be called from another application. I installed the Ruby daemon Gem and I did the test program. Can any one please give me the step by step sample. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you add some background information... Your question looks a little bit unstructured...

Comment: What platform are you running on? Creating a daemon depends on the os

Comment: I need to run on Linux Box. I am Using DRb concept. IS this the Right way? In the DRb Server file i coded all the necessary action. from the client program i connect the DRb object & i called the method i defined in DRb server

Comment: It's friday but are we really doing daemons now? ;)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to investigate the [daemon-kit](http://github.com/kennethkalmer/daemon-kit/tree/master) library, which provides a nice skeleton structure for various kinds of daemons.  Your use case might actually be well-served by an [AMQP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Message_Queuing_Protocol) daemon.

Answer (score 1):

There's a great reference on DRb: [DRb API](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/drb/rdoc/index.html)
And I found a tutorial [here](http://amazing-development.com/archives/2006/03/16/rails-and-distributed-ruby-in-a-nutshell/), and another one by [DRBrain](http://segment7.net/projects/ruby/drb/introduction.html).

I've been researching this for my own hobby project.  Unfortunately, I think there's a language barrier which is preventing a more in depth question.  I'm sorry your question got voted down.  Maybe, if you posted it in english and your own language, in conjunction with BabelFish maybe we'd be better able to answer your question.  I'm interested in SO user's take on this subject, as DRb is very important to my hobby app (alright alright, it's a game.  :P)

Hope this helps.

[Edit: my own English is very sucky pre-coffee]